# How to sync multiple folders of GitHub repo to a single AzureGit using Azure CI CD process

Tags: git, azure, continuous-integration, cd, azure-git-deployment

I am new to Git. 
I have a public repo in GitHub which i like to sync with my Azure Git. The scenario is like below

GitHub has multiple folders and files with no parent folder. I want to have these folders, files copied to my Azure Git using Azure CI CD process under a parent folder only.

I tried to depict in attached diagram. 
[Git Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4zmX.png)

How can i achieve this? Code snippet would help me better as i am new to Git.

Note: I have to use the Azure CI CD process hence there wont be any permanent place where I can put up the code/branches. It would always run in Build Agent which will change in every execution.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using the Azure CI CD process, I don’t need to pull specifically the source code at least. Its handled by the Build pipeline. Next are the few steps which I figured out on my own (lot of hit and trial) to handle the situation mentioned in question.

Basically I moved the content of source repository (GitHub repo content) to a folder (**Parent Folder "Y"**) having same name as of the **Parent Folder** in destination Azure Git. And then pushed the content of this newly created folder.

1. *robocopy $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) $(Agent.WorkFolder)\**Parent Folder Y**\ /e /move*

This **Parent Folder Y** is the parent folder name under which I wanted to push the changes in my Azure Git (Destination).

2. robocopy $(Agent.WorkFolder)\**Parent Folder Y** $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**Parent Folder Y**\ /e /move
3. cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\"**Parent Folder Y**"
4. git pull https://$(token)@xyzteam.visualstudio.com/_git/Your_Repo _Name BranchName
5. git push https://$(token)@xyzteam.visualstudio.com/_git/Your_Repo _Name head:BranchName